# Remove a Twitter Bootstrap dropdown toggle method at a certain breakpoint

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, expressionengine

Hoping someone can help with this.

I'm using twitter bootstrap to create a dropdown/dropup menu for a responsive site. I have a dropup menu item, at the bottom of my site, that holds a big list of links that is inserted via ajax (using the [filament group AJAX pattern](https://github.com/filamentgroup/Ajax-Include-Pattern)) if the screen size is > 50em. If it is < 50em I'd like the `<a>` to function as normal and take the user off to the sitemap page.

In my JS file I have this to pull in the list of links. *Nothing special is included for the dropdowns as that is handled by bootstrap.js*

```
$("[data-append],[data-replace],[data-after],[data-before]").ajaxInclude();
```

And in the HTML

```
<nav class="dropup sitemap pull-left" id="sitemap">
<div class="dropdown" data-append="/includes/footer-sitemap" data-media="(min-width: 50em)">
    <a href="{path=sitemap}" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="menu-sitmap">Sitemap <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <ul>
            <!-- List of links -->
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

My question is how can reverse the function that is stopping the sitemap link from being followed, but only if the window is < 50em?

Comment: Have a look a enquire.js and using the jQuery `off()` to clear and bootstrap dropdowns